# Error when using ALSA plugin dsnoop

Tags: audio, alsa

I want to record audio from a webcam from two different programs, that is, I want to execute "arecord" from two different places.
The problem is that you cannot do this, since you will get the error: the device is already busy.

I have been researching and the solution is to use the dsnoop ALSA plugin, which I do not manage to make work.

My .asoundrc file is as follows:

```
pcm.example {

    type dsnoop
            slave {
            pcm "hw:0,0"
            channels 1
    }

}
```

Therefore, when I try to execute:

```
sudo arecord -D example test.wav
```

I get the error:

```
 ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM example
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.asoundrc` is in your user's home directory. But when using `sudo`, the device must be defined in root's home directory.
(Alternatively, put it into `/etc/asound.conf` for all users.)

Comment: now I get this: ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1605:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card